# Fitting to Poisson histogram

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I am trying to fit a curve over the histogram of a Poisson distribution that looks like this
[image: histo]

I have modified the fit function so that it resembles a Poisson distribution, with the parameter t as a variable. But the curve_fit function can not be plotted and I am not sure why.

```
def histo(bsize):
    N = bsize
    #binwidth
    bw = (dt.max()-dt.min())/(N-1.)
    bin1 = dt.min()+ bw*np.arange(N)
    #define the array to hold the occurrence count
    bincount= np.array([])
    for bin in bin1:
        count = np.where((dt>=bin)&(dt<bin+bw))[0].size
        bincount = np.append(bincount,count)
    #bin center
    binc = bin1+0.5*bw
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(binc,bincount,drawstyle= 'steps-mid')
    plt.xlabel("Interval[ticks]")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
histo(30)
plt.xlim(0,.5e8)
plt.ylim(0,25000)
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
delta_t = 1.42e7
def func(x, t):
    return t * np.exp(- delta_t/t) 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, np.arange(0,.5e8),histo(30))
plt.plot(popt)
```

Comment: Can you provide the trace back?  I strongly suspect that you do not understand what `curve_fit` is returning.  See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Two things: 1) You don't need to write your own histogram function, just use [`np.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and 2) Never fit a curve to a histogram if you have the actual data, do a fit to the data itself using [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#fitting-distributions)

Comment: 3) what you implemented as `func` is not a poisson

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you do not know what the return values of `curve_fit` are. It is the parameters for the fit-function and their covariance matrix - not something you can plot directly.

### Binned Least-Squares Fit

In general you can get everything much, much more easily:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import factorial
from scipy.stats import poisson

# get poisson deviated random numbers
data = np.random.poisson(2, 1000)

# the bins should be of integer width, because poisson is an integer distribution
bins = np.arange(11) - 0.5
entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=bins, density=True, label='Data')

# calculate bin centers
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])


def fit_function(k, lamb):
    '''poisson function, parameter lamb is the fit parameter'''
    return poisson.pmf(k, lamb)


# fit with curve_fit
parameters, cov_matrix = curve_fit(fit_function, bin_centers, entries)

# plot poisson-deviation with fitted parameter
x_plot = np.arange(0, 15)

plt.plot(
    x_plot,
    fit_function(x_plot, *parameters),
    marker='o', linestyle='',
    label='Fit result',
)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image: binned fit]

### Unbinned Maximum-Likelihood fit

An even better possibility would be to not use a histogram at all
and instead to carry out a maximum-likelihood fit.

But by closer examination even this is unnecessary, because the
maximum-likelihood estimator for the parameter of the poissonian distribution is the arithmetic mean.

However, if you have other, more complicated PDFs, you can use this as example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.special import factorial
from scipy import stats


def poisson(k, lamb):
    """poisson pdf, parameter lamb is the fit parameter"""
    return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)


def negative_log_likelihood(params, data):
    """
    The negative log-Likelihood-Function
    """

    lnl = - np.sum(np.log(poisson(data, params[0])))
    return lnl

def negative_log_likelihood(params, data):
    ''' better alternative using scipy '''
    return -stats.poisson.logpmf(data, params[0]).sum()


# get poisson deviated random numbers
data = np.random.poisson(2, 1000)

# minimize the negative log-Likelihood

result = minimize(negative_log_likelihood,  # function to minimize
                  x0=np.ones(1),            # start value
                  args=(data,),             # additional arguments for function
                  method='Powell',          # minimization method, see docs
                  )
# result is a scipy optimize result object, the fit parameters 
# are stored in result.x
print(result)

# plot poisson-distribution with fitted parameter
x_plot = np.arange(0, 15)

plt.plot(
    x_plot,
    stats.poisson.pmf(x_plot, result.x),
    marker='o', linestyle='',
    label='Fit result',
)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is great for fitting a curve to data points, and it's the correct answer to the question as asked, in the programming sense.  However, if you are fitting to poissonian data, scientifically/statistically you'll be better off to fit to the sample itself, not the histogram!

Comment: Of Course, I will ads this to my answer.

Comment: I added an unbinned likelihood fit

Comment: How do I make sure that my bin widths are integer valued?

Comment: You can give an array of bin edges to the bins keyword, using something like `bins =  np.arange(0, N, 1) - 0.5` will give you ` N - 2` bins  with integer width and integer center

Comment: @MaxNoe thanks a lot, I understand now. By the way I asked another normalization question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164239/gamma-fit-of-a-histogram-normalization-issues), your help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Might it be worth adding that the MLE for the lambda parameter, is simply the sample mean? We don't really need any of this then, since that is a known result.

Comment: It is there. Second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the wonderful discussion!

You might want to consider the following:

1) Instead of computing "poisson", compute "log poisson", for better numerical behavior

2) Instead of using "lamb", use the logarithm (let me call it "log_mu"), to avoid the fit "wandering" into negative values of "mu".
So

```
log_poisson(k, log_mu): return k*log_mu - loggamma(k+1) - math.exp(log_mu)
```

Where "loggamma" is the `scipy.special.loggamma` function.

Actually, in the above fit, the "loggamma" term only adds a constant offset to the functions being minimized, so one can just do:

```
log_poisson_(k, log_mu): return k*log_mu - math.exp(log_mu)
```

NOTE: `log_poisson_()` not the same as `log_poisson()`, but when used for minimization in the manner above, will give the same fitted minimum (the same value of mu, up to numerical issues).  The value of the function being minimized will have been offset, but one doesn't usually care about that anyway.