# Determining if data in a txt file obeys certain statistics

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working with a Geiger counter which can be hooked up to a computer and which records its output in the form of a .txt file, NC.txt, where it records the time since starting and the 'value' of the radiation it recorded. It looks like

```
import pylab
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1 = []
y1 = []
#Define a dictionary: counts
f = open("NC.txt", "r")
for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   parts = line.split(",") #the columns are separated by commas and spaces
   time = float(parts[1])  #time is recorded in the second column of NC.txt
   value = float(parts[2]) #and the value it records is in the third
   x1.append(time)
   y1.append(value)
f.close()

xv = np.array(x1)
yv = np.array(y1)

#Statistics
m = np.mean(yv)
d = np.std(yv)
#Strip out background radiation
trueval = yv - m

#Basic plot of counts
num_bins = 10000
plt.hist(trueval,num_bins)
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

So this code so far will just create a simple histogram of the radiation counts centred at zero, so the background radiation is ignored.

What I want to do now is perform a chi-squared test to see how well the data fits, say, Poisson statistics (and then go on to compare it with other distributions later). I'm not really sure how to do that. I have access to scipy and numpy, so I feel like this should be a simple task, but just learning python as I go here, so I'm not a terrific programmer.

Does anyone know of a straightforward way to do this?

Edit for clarity: I'm not asking so much about if there is a chi-squared function or not. I'm more interested in how to compare it with other statistical distributions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check here how to do fits (particoularly of poisson functions) with scipy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram

Answer (score 0):

You can use SciPy library, [here is documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) and examples.

Comment: I'm aware of this, since I import the scipy module in the code, but my question is really about comparison with other statistics, not if such a chi-squared function exists.It is not quite clear to me how this is done.

Comment: you could pass historical data with `f_exp` into the function and see how your outcome changes