# Compare Histogram to Poisson Distribution and Gauss-Curve

Tags: python, histogram, poisson

I got 100 experimental values:

```
N = np.array([ 6080, 5604, 5972, 5566, 5683, 5619, 5582, 5912, 5614,5837, 5961, 5972, 5807, 5829, 5881, 5757, 5725, 5809, 5626, 5995, 5793, 5608, 5880, 5982, 5748, 6071, 6181, 6034, 6117, 5903, 6190, 5735, 6109, 6126, 6012, 5948, 6139, 6103, 6108, 6031, 6200, 6091, 6199, 6165, 6591, 5803, 6093, 5921, 6194, 5799, 6020, 6156, 6129, 6344, 6243, 6122, 5926, 5904, 5579, 5881, 6157, 5925, 5835, 5778, 6125, 5737, 5703, 5809, 6109, 5978, 5881, 6250, 6143, 5658, 5815, 5633, 5780, 5620, 6180, 5770, 6058, 5688, 5792, 6170, 5915, 6147, 5727, 6300, 6049, 6263, 6168, 6156, 6071, 6196, 6078, 5848, 5847, 6248, 6243, 6084])
```

Now I want to compare this with a Poisson-Distribution and Gaussian-Distribution. 
I want to put the Curves on Top of my histogram:

[image: enter image description here]]

But it doesn't work. 
For e.g. with the Poisson-Distribution: I want to make a Fit of Poisson-Distribution which lays over my Histogram

```
b = np.sqrt(len(N)) 
w = np.ones_like(N)/float(len(N))

entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(N, bins=b, weights=w)


def poisson(x, lamb):
    return (lamb**x/factorial(x)) * np.exp(-lamb) 

parameters, cov_matrx = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries)
```

But when I plot it, its not even near

```
plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, *parameters), 'r-', lw=2)
```

[image: Where is Poisson?]

How would you solve such a Problem? I think its because my values are too high. The Poisson Distr. runs with k = 0, 1, 2, ....
Mine are like k' = 6000, 6200, ...

Comment: I've been trying to test this in my own environment, but i'm having trouble understanding how you passed poisson into curve_fit? I'm getting a warning `Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated` out. Can you show a more complete excerpt of your code?

Comment: yeah, same for me. I used this guide which works.. I dont know why it doesnt with my values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plot there is a red line...it's the Poisson curve. What lambda are you using? It's very likely too small and you get only zeroes.
Anyway I suggest you to use: [poisson](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html#scipy.stats.poisson) function from scipy

```
def poisson(x, lamb):
    from scipy.stats import poisson as _poisson    
    return _poisson.pmf(x,lamb)

parameters, cov_matrx = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries, p0=6000)
```

You should also add `normed=True` to your first histogram plot

```
entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(N, bins=b, weights=w, normed=True)
```

Comment: I tried to work similiarly to this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram ... I thought 'curve_fit' calculates my lambda. Doesnt it? For each bin I calculated the bin_middle. The bin_middles and the count or likelihood are my x,y from which I make a curve_fit...

Comment: I linked the wrong function... I edited my post...try using that instead of your implementation of poisson...anyway what is the estimated lambda?

Comment: Isnt it: 'lambda = np.mean(N)' ? The mean of my array? Anyway: I wanted curve_fit to calculate the best lambda for me.... I am confused right now. Thank you for link.

Comment: yes, I have understood that...i am asking what is the result of `curve_fit`. Have you tried the scipy version? I suspect that is just a numerical problem

Comment: Ok lambda seems to be '1' when I print the parameters. Still have the same error 'OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)'.

Comment: updated my post...I think you should give a reasonable hint on lambda...by default it starts from 1

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to " Im a new member; can you invite me to a Chat maybe? I tried to use p0=6000 or p0=np.mean(N) ... it gives: RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600.

Comment: Wrong call: Now I used your updated answer one for one. Still: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning) ...and a red line (which represents my Poisson-Curve) at the bottom.

Comment: you should also add `normed=True` to your first histogram plot