# gaussian-fit for histograms without outlier

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, gaussian

I need to plot three distributions (histograms) of three different arrays composed of elements that stay more or less in the same range (let's say from 0.0 to 0.6). I therefore use `f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)`, for what concerns the plot.

Now, I also want to fit a gaussian to these three different histograms, but without considering the outliers. That is, each distribution gets different limits again.

What I do obtain, is either I do remove completely the outliers both from the plot (and therefore from the histogram, thus obtaining a good fitting gaussian), or I do limit the distributions arrays, in which case the gaussian stays "low" (in frequence) with respect to the real gaussian.

Any suggestions?

Here is part of the plot I have been using:

```
# values = one of my three arrays
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
bins1 = np.histogram([i for i in values if 0.05<i<0.25], bins = 50)[1] # this is if I want to limit the array values to a certain range - but see above
ax1.hist(values, bins1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
num_1, bins_1  = np.histogram([i for i in values if 0.05<i<0.25], bins1)
bins_01 = [0.5 * (bins_1[i] + bins_1[i+1]) for i in range(len(bins_1)-1)]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, bins_01, num_1) # "gaussian" is an already defined function
x_fit = py.linspace(bins_01[0], bins_01[-1], 100)
y_fit = gaussian(x_fit, *popt)
ax1.plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'r--', linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Do not fit the histograms. You just loose information by using the binned values. Just calculate mean and sample standard deviation and plot the gaussian distribution.

Comment: If you really do want to fit the histogram, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram

Comment: @MaxNoe, I do want to fit the histogram, but only its peak. And I also want to plot the fitted gaussian.

Comment: Why do you want to fit the histogram? Do you not have access to the unbinned values? It is generally a bad idea to fit a histogram if you have the unbinned values.

Comment: It depends on the binning. And on the data. Do you suggest to simply find mean and standard deviation of my data and plot that gaussian?

Comment: Yes, as these are the maximum likelihood estimators for the parameters of a gaussian distribution. (standard deviation with `ddof=1`)

Comment: Also, a way better way for selecting data in a certain value space with numpy arrays are boolean indeces. Like this: `values[(values > 0) & (values < 0.25)]`

Comment: @MaxNoe, what do you suggest to plot the gaussian? [mlab.normpdf](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.normpdf) is appropriate?

Comment: My first idea would be scipy.stats.norm, it has also a fit method

Comment: @MaxNoe, ok, but this plots a gaussian that is lower with respect to the peaks of the histogram distribution... This is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You have either to normalize the histogram or multiply the PDF by the area of the hist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114475/discussion-between-py-ser-and-maxnoe).