# Poisson distribution does not fit a count data?

Tags: python, distribution

My data set is count data which evolves per time. This is an example of my counter

```
y=[36562, 37572, 37673, 40097, 43632, 44541, 46662,...]
x=[1550568198, 1550568228, 1550568230, 1550568316, 1550568403, 1550568427, 1550568480,...]
```

y is the counter, x is the timestamp. 
At first, I think that it follows a Poisson regression. But, when I tried to verify my hypothesis, I don't find the expected fitting.

To summarize, this is what I did: I compute the slopes regression for my data. Then I plot their histogram. After that, I compute the mean of my slopes and I implement  Poisson function. I am not sure about how to 
make the bins. I try to see some example in stackoverflow to complete my code  such as: [Fitting to Poisson histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram) .

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    from scipy.misc import factorial


    data = [27.40041970809832, 32.52317791169886,27.3324477289847, 29.68905709156824, 27.44566022922384, 27.026161302807385, 29.675405306658636, 29.564830205097582, 28.56067637508962,
            23.60753361275924, 25.316041848299914, 27.317775979592117, 35.73282187625897, 30.32225651126249, 27.03607257379792, 24.362222897893748, 24.65336563751245, 28.450358510355684,
            22.368137524840183, 21.806818181818183, 25.75260663507109, 24.987645788182324, 34.967668159429635, 23.499847328244275, 28.529195384496244, 27.500729278406943, 28.469798657718123,
            27.537244578565765, 23.74425395856262, 34.48780487804878, 31.772625997058952, 31.664898269594048, 28.301003506226575,  22.64477255843191, 25.603392292708463,
            28.532267426704433, 28.348878956792305, 22.58896035480437, 39.06362540925434, 32.04016020681587, 21.58951676789015, 32.83273314521246, 31.727921698547654, 28.65265545309064,
            30.494659177316855, 30.74716621971587, 32.08999140523891, 25.183941087174187, 26.832174094355985, 35.525273605225856, 35.01295936313986, 39.266832762077264, 35.61519504409594,
            35.91467612971841, 36.71106192425408, 36.34885885239447, 40.416662916970395, 35.091398942237895, 37.01203044872287, 28.197121855591625, 21.854931292398675, 26.743631918874872,
            29.762268179981486, 24.006539900770527, 25.72427714455481, 30.67491009723373, 34.81656473907885, 25.13364055299539, 25.99602399934977, 30.729181632314745, 26.54844439266593,
            27.72187375633894, 25.18792552710094, 24.3886052143513, 27.067946681498317, 33.299243838491385, 23.92990365124911, 23.84023229569779, 33.666666666666664, 26.89725332337826,
            25.550380234958652, 23.99372754399854, 25.84107642228557, 26.123970016846528, 33.978022127956066, 27.82255764105657, 41.88764012240061, 40.8010411982126, 42.52112969664627,
            35.35, 38.15555555555556, 42.36181832077762, 42.9746324840747, 42.31232446076512, 42.812821020682215, 28.94784168070659, 29.507471050086778, 31.80253624835235,
            22.536153708802047, 35.08649932914553, 29.304744525547445, 20.7255675376875, 36.11658202084377, 31.711820847979265, 24.839882636487474, 23.770794763290134, 25.637843838454483,
            28.09964085709791, 26.241279743392024, 22.848554093452048, 30.020613652137627, 30.021908277120186, 23.2027027027027, 23.43360400170476, 24.218992074949888, 24.012712502779962,
           26.689668934874973, 25.97142857142857, 25.751828434803443, 30.72578185955838, 25.18743583902151, 24.067986343641255, 27.545454545454547, 24.571980318768663, 26.736357070752664,
            23.394701805671342, 25.938323964418938, 28.57385792553413, 22.444444444444443, 23.348723005916924]



# minimize the negative log-Likelihood

result = minimize(negLogLikelihood,  # function to minimize
                  x0=np.ones(1),     # start value
                  args=(data,),      # additional arguments for function
                  method='Powell',   # minimization method, see docs
                  )
# result is a scipy optimize result object, the fit parameters
# are stored in result.x
print(result)

# plot poisson-deviation with fitted parameter
x_plot = np.linspace(0, 40, 1000)
plt.xlabel('Parameter_Slope')
plt.ylabel('P(Parameter_Slope)')
plt.hist(data,bins=30, density=True, color='b')
plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, result.x), 'r-', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

So please, are there mistakes in my code that causes the non-fitting of my data ? How to make a suitable fitting for my data?

Also,  When I change these two lines to:

```
x_plot = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)

plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(15) - 0.5, normed=True)
```

the  histogram disappears, so I can not check if the curve fit matches my data. 
[image]

Comment: At lambda=10 Poisson already is pretty symmetric and close to Gaussian distribution. You have mean value circa 26, so your Poisson would be even more Gaussian in shape, symmetric etc. What you have on hands is clearly asymmetric, with secondary peaks, some non-zero skew histogram - Poisson is not a good fit IMHO

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux  Ok so according to you my data may follow gaussian distribution ?

Comment: To me this hist looks like it _COULD_ fit a poisson distribution, but you're trying to plot a histogram on 20<x<45, 0<y<30 on the same scale as a poisson PDF with a much much smaller scale and not centered on the mean of your distribution. Perhaps plotting the poisson line on a secondary y axis might help

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you very much for your help. Firstly, is it the strategy that I follow by plotting the  the histrogram based on slopes, correct or not? Secondly, Could you please help me to correct my code  based on your opinion please? I don't really understand  very well what is the  the poisson line on a secondary y axis  mean?

Comment: [Here's question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram) that may help you, might be worth reading through

Comment: @dina no, it cannot be gaussian - you have asymmetric, with a skew, distribution. What I'm saying, at lambda=26 your Poisson and Gaussian would be pretty much one and the same - symmetric, close to 0 skew. It is clearly not what you have - you have to look at your model and check for another distribution which could fit in

Comment: @G.Anderson  I try the second answer  that you have notice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828184/fitting-to-poisson-histogram  But I am still not sure about the obtained results

Comment: There seem to be several questions here: 1.  Is my data Poisson distributed  2.  How do I fit a Poisson distribution to my data  3.  How do I overlay a plot of a given Poisson distribution with a histogram.  If the answer to #1 is "no" do you still care about questions 2 and 3?

Comment: @John Of course no. But I need to find the best distribution to my data.  So please if you have  any suggestion I would very grateful.

Comment: Are you able to talk about the source of your data?

Comment: @John in fact it is a network simulation. The y is  a network counter timer able to compute the number of timeslot in a network.  x is just a timestamp.  I compute slopes for my data. Based on these slopes I try to find the best distribution and extract the confidence interval.  Is it clear ?

Comment: Your data would look much closer to a Poisson distribution if you shifted the x values by the minimum for which you have any counts.  x might not be Poisson but x-xmin might be.

Comment: @John are you talking about x in the histrogram ? or x the timestamp of my data? My slopes depend essentially  on y values.

Comment: I was confused.  I misread and thought that histogram was of your actual data.  It's not clear to me what parameter_slope is or why you should need it.  You should be able to fit a Poisson distribution to your raw count data.

Comment: @John  Thank you very much for your help. I said that I am not sure about what I did. I am really confused. I see, I read through my research that I must compute the slopes. I have a counter; Which logically must follow a poisson distribution.  When I compute their slopes I feel I am lost

Comment: Are you using the slopes (dy/dx) as a surrogate for the number of events in each x-interval because your raw count data is cumulative?

Comment: @John In fact no. I  have many simulations. Every simulation is about 15 minutes. I compute the slope of every simulation and I plot the final results in an histogram to check the distribution. I thins this is the mistake.

Comment: So for each simulation you get a counts vs time curve?  And this curve is roughly linear and you take the slope of that curve?  And you expect that slope to behave according to a Poisson distribution?

Comment: @John  For each simulation, I count the number of a specific event. I plot the curve of my count. I extract its slope. And I expect that all  resulted slopes will follow  a poisson distribution.

Comment: Is the curve always precisely linear or do you have to do a regression in order to generate the slope?  What's the reason that you should expect the slopes to be Poisson distributed?  Looking at the data you provided, they would appear to be drawn from a continuous rather than discrete distribution to me.

Comment: My  data curve is linear. To extract the slopes I use a linear regression scipy.stats.linregress(x, y) . I said that my slopes follows a poisson regression because the origin of my data is a counter. I admit that I am not good in fitting and extraction distribution. If you have any proposition I would be really very grateful